# Taking all values from a dataLayer

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

From google tag manager in console in google chrome typing `dataLayer` I can see all object of dataLayer with there value. Typing this `dataLayer.push()` I can see the number of object.

What should I type to take the object with there values and save them to a new variable?

Answer (score 1):

```
dataLayer.length
```

is the proper way of returning the number of objects in the dataLayer.

To get the value of a particular parameter in GTM, you need to define a new variable of type "Data Layer". The name of the key would be used in this new variable.

Once you have defined the variable, you can use it you return the value of the key used to configure the variable.

For example if your dataLayer was

```
dataLayer = [{
   'animal': 'elephant'
]}
```

then your GTM variable would be configured with 'animal', and you could name this variable 'myAnimal'. Whenever you call this variable with {{my animal}}, it should return 'elephant'.